# AWS API Gateway IAM Authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam

I have a group of aws api gateways which I am trying to restrict access to them through only one internal lambda function. I created a role, added the AmazonAPIGatewayInvokeFullAccess policy to it and assigned this role to the lambda function. However, I am still not able to access the APIs from the lambda and getting 403s. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Under IAM you need to add trust relationship with apigateway.amazonaws.com

[image: AWS IAM Describing the trusted relationship]

Comment: Thank you. I updated the policy but still having the same problem.            {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": [
          "apigateway.amazonaws.com",
          "lambda.amazonaws.com"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: Next one to check is whether custom authorizer returns the reponse as documented. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/use-custom-authorizer.html . Perform a console.log of the response and check whether the response matches to documentation. I have a working Authorizer, it tooks bit of time to figure it out.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't even know that I need a custom authorizer to get api gateway IAM auth to work. Do I ?